# Relative paths in XML catalogs are treated differently on windows and linux using XJC

Tags: jaxb, xjc

We use XJC version "JAXB 2.1.10 in JDK 6" (by using jaxb2-maven-plugin) to generate JAXB classes based on OGC's WFS 2.0. 
We use a catalog file for resolving schemas the WFS schema depends on. The entries in the catalog file reference schemas on the file system by using relative paths, e.g.

```
<catalog xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:entity:xmlns:xml:catalog" prefer="system">

    <rewriteSystem
        systemIdStartString="http://www.w3.org/2001/"
        rewritePrefix="../../2001/"/>

    <rewriteSystem
        systemIdStartString="http://www.w3.org/1999/"
        rewritePrefix="../../w3c/"/>

    <rewriteSystem
        systemIdStartString="http://schemas.opengis.net/ows/1.1/"
        rewritePrefix="../../ows/1.1.0/"/>

    <rewriteSystem
        systemIdStartString="http://schemas.opengis.net/ows/1.1.0/"
        rewritePrefix="../../ows/1.1.0/"/>

    <rewriteSystem
        systemIdStartString="http://schemas.opengis.net/filter/2.0/"
        rewritePrefix="../../filter/2.0/"/>

</catalog>
```

This is working fine on linux, but on windows, we get a *java.io.FileNotFoundException* for each file defined in the catalog. It makes no difference whether XJC is called by the maven plugin or directly, the behaviour is the same. 
In fact, we didn't manage to make XJC work on windows using relative paths in the catalog at all.

Excerpt of the log running mvn -X clean install:

```
+ Error stacktraces are turned on.
Apache Maven 2.2.1 (r801777; 2009-08-06 21:16:01+0200)
Java version: 1.6.0_20
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\jre
Default locale: de_DE, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7" version: "6.1" arch: "amd64" Family: "windows"
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:1.5:xjc' -->
[DEBUG]   (f) bindingDirectory = C:\dev\depot\myproject\src\main\xsd\wfs\2.0
[DEBUG]   (f) catalog = C:\dev\depot\myproject\src\main\xsd\wfs\2.0\wfs.cat
[DEBUG]   (f) clearOutputDir = false
[DEBUG]   (f) dtd = false
[DEBUG]   (f) enableIntrospection = false
[DEBUG]   (f) encoding = UTF-8
[DEBUG]   (f) explicitAnnotation = false
[DEBUG]   (f) extension = false
[DEBUG]   (f) failOnNoSchemas = true
[DEBUG]   (f) npa = false
[DEBUG]   (f) nv = false
[DEBUG]   (f) outputDirectory = C:\dev\depot\myproject\target\generated-sources\jaxb
[DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: com.myproject:MyProject:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT @ C:\dev\depot\myproject\pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) quiet = false
[DEBUG]   (f) readOnly = false
[DEBUG]   (f) relaxng = false
[DEBUG]   (f) relaxngCompact = false
[DEBUG]   (f) schemaDirectory = C:\dev\depot\myproject\src\main\xsd\wfs\2.0
[DEBUG]   (f) staleFile = C:\dev\depot\myproject\target\stale\wfs\2.0
[DEBUG]   (f) verbose = false
[DEBUG]   (f) wsdl = false
[DEBUG]   (f) xmlschema = true
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[INFO] [jaxb2:xjc {execution: wfs}]
[DEBUG] Using XJC of JAXB Reference Implementation  version 2.1.13
[DEBUG] The schema Directory is C:\dev\depot\myproject\src\main\xsd\wfs\2.0
[DEBUG] accept false for file C:\dev\depot\myproject\src\main\xsd\wfs\2.0\CVS
[DEBUG] accept false for file C:\dev\depot\myproject\src\main\xsd\wfs\2.0\wfs.cat
[DEBUG] accept false for file C:\dev\depot\myproject\src\main\xsd\wfs\2.0\wfs.xjb
[DEBUG] accept true for file C:\dev\depot\myproject\src\main\xsd\wfs\2.0\wfs.xsd
[DEBUG] The binding Directory is C:\dev\depot\myproject\src\main\xsd\wfs\2.0
[INFO] Generating source...
[DEBUG] C:\dev\depot\myproject\target\classes
[DEBUG] D:\mvnrep\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.3\commons-codec-1.3.jar
[DEBUG] D:\mvnrep\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.6\commons-lang-2.6.jar
[DEBUG] D:\mvnrep\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.1.2\httpclient-4.1.2.jar
[DEBUG] D:\mvnrep\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.1.2\httpcore-4.1.2.jar
[DEBUG] D:\mvnrep\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.1\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
[DEBUG] The binding Directory is C:\dev\depot\myproject\src\main\xsd\wfs\2.0
[DEBUG] accept false for file C:\dev\depot\myproject\src\main\xsd\wfs\2.0\CVS
[DEBUG] accept false for file C:\dev\depot\myproject\src\main\xsd\wfs\2.0\wfs.cat
[DEBUG] accept false for file C:\dev\depot\myproject\src\main\xsd\wfs\2.0\wfs.xjb
[DEBUG] accept true for file C:\dev\depot\myproject\src\main\xsd\wfs\2.0\wfs.xsd
[DEBUG] JAXB XJC args: [-xmlschema, -catalog, C:\dev\depot\myproject\src\main\xsd\wfs\2.0\wfs.cat, -d, C:\dev\depot\myproject\target\generated-sources\jaxb, -classpath, C:\dev\depot\myproject\target\classes;D:\mvnrep\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.3\commons-codec-1.3.jar;D:\mvnrep\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.6\commons-lang-2.6.jar;D:\mvnrep\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.1.2\httpclient-4.1.2.jar;D:\mvnrep\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.1.2\httpcore-4.1.2.jar;D:\mvnrep\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.1\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;, -b, C:\dev\depot\myproject\src\main\xsd\wfs\2.0\wfs.xjb, C:\dev\depot\myproject\src\main\xsd\wfs\2.0]
[INFO] parsing a schema...
[ERROR] null[-1,-1]
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\dev\depot\myproject\owsGetResourceByID.xsd (Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ErrorReceiver.error(ErrorReceiver.java:90)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.DOMForest.parse(DOMForest.java:401)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.DOMForest.parse(DOMForest.java:300)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.AbstractReferenceFinderImpl.startElement(AbstractReferenceFinderImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:501)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:179)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:377)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2755)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.DOMForest.parse(DOMForest.java:393)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.DOMForest.parse(DOMForest.java:300)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.AbstractReferenceFinderImpl.startElement(AbstractReferenceFinderImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:501)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:179)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:377)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2755)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.DOMForest.parse(DOMForest.java:393)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.DOMForest.parse(DOMForest.java:273)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.buildDOMForest(ModelLoader.java:321)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.loadXMLSchema(ModelLoader.java:374)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:167)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:113)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver.run(Driver.java:313)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.jaxb2.AbstractXjcMojo.execute(AbstractXjcMojo.java:327)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
...
[INFO] Failed to parse a schema.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Could not process schema files in directory C:\dev\depot\myproject\src\main\xsd\wfs\2.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Trace
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Could not process schema files in directory C:\dev\depot\myproject\src\main\xsd\wfs\2.0
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:719)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Could not process schema files in directory C:\dev\depot\myproject\src\main\xsd\wfs\2.0
    at org.codehaus.mojo.jaxb2.AbstractXjcMojo.execute(AbstractXjcMojo.java:343)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
    ... 17 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1 second
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Nov 11 06:56:54 CET 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 25M/181M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Did somebody face similar problems and was able to find a solution?

**Note:**
 - Using absolute paths is not a solution as we want it to work on both linux and windows
 - Using a newer version of XJC/JAXB is not an option at the moment
 - Using the "OGC Schemas and Tools Project" is not an option as we want full control of the generation process and the classes for the WFS schema are just a side product of the generation of classes for custom schemas. Generating classes for WFS is just an example.

Comment: Have you seen this: https://github.com/highsource/ogc-schemas

Comment: And why is `Using the "OGC Schemas and Tools Project artifacts"` not an option?

Comment: What is it trying to use as your working directory?

Answer (score 1):

When reporting this kind of things, always post `mvn -X install`. Logs and stack traces tell *a lot*. My [maven-jaxb2-plugin](/questions/tagged/maven-jaxb2-plugin), for instance, logs (among others) debug info from the catalog resolver, so you'd see something like:

```
resolveSystem(file:/C:/Projects/workspaces/mj2p/maven-jaxb2-plugin-project/tests/gh-issue-16/src/main/resources/ab/a.xsd)
resolveSystem(file:/C:/Projects/workspaces/mj2p/maven-jaxb2-plugin-project/tests/gh-issue-16/src/main/resources/ab/a.xsd)
resolveSystem(http://www.ab.org/b.xsd)
Resolved system: http://www.ab.org/b.xsd
    file:/C:/Projects/workspaces/mj2p/maven-jaxb2-plugin-project/tests/gh-issue-16/src/main/resources/ab/b.xsd
resolveSystem(http://www.ab.org/b.xsd)
```

I've just put up a [small test project](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/tree/master/tests/gh-issue-16) to test it, so I can actually confirm that *relative paths in catalogs do work*. At least with [maven-jaxb2-plugin](/questions/tagged/maven-jaxb2-plugin) and JAXB 2.2.11. This is the [catalog file](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/blob/master/tests/gh-issue-16/src/main/resources/ab/catalog.cat) I used:

```
REWRITE_SYSTEM "http://www.ab.org" "../ab"
```

**Important note:** files are resolved *relatively to the catalog file* itself. I have put the catalog file under `src/main/resources/ab/catalog.cat` and `http://www.ab.org/b.xsd` got resolved to `src/main/resources/ab/b.xsd`.

And finally, have you seen the [`ogc-schemas`](https://github.com/highsource/ogc-schemas) project on GitHub? It is the continuation of my old [OGC Schemas and Tools](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/OGCS/Home) project, it compiles OGC Schemas with JAXB XJC. The WFS schema you need is [already compiled](https://github.com/highsource/ogc-schemas/tree/master/wfs/2.0) there, you can either use the artifact or compile it on your own using the provided [binding files](https://github.com/highsource/ogc-schemas/blob/master/wfs/2.0/src/main/resources/wfs-v_2_0.xjb).

By the way, how I hande compilation in the [`ogc-schemas`](https://github.com/highsource/ogc-schemas) project:

- I first package all the schemas [in a separate artifact](https://github.com/highsource/ogc-schemas/tree/master/schemas).
- I define a [catalog file](https://github.com/highsource/ogc-schemas/blob/master/schemas/src/main/resources/ogc/catalog.cat) with a rewriting rule to rewrite all the `http://schemas.opengis.net/...` URLs to that Maven artifact:

> REWRITE_SYSTEM "http://schemas.opengis.net" "maven:org.jvnet.ogc:ogc-schemas:jar::!/ogc"

- In per schema modules I just compile absolute URLs like [`http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/2.0/wfs.xsd`](https://github.com/highsource/ogc-schemas/blob/master/wfs/2.0/pom.xml#L48)
- My [maven-jaxb2-plugin](/questions/tagged/maven-jaxb2-plugin) resolves everything to the Maven artifact from the step one. Effectively, all the schemas are loaded from the local JAR built on that step.

I think your problem is that URLs are resolved relatively but relatively to the catalog file and this is probably not what you expect.

**Disclaimer:** I am the author of the [maven-jaxb2-plugin](/questions/tagged/maven-jaxb2-plugin) and the [`ogc-schemas`](https://github.com/highsource/ogc-schemas) project mentioned above.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that we gave maven-jaxb2-plugin a try and relative paths actually work with that plugin in a windows environment. However, it's not an option to use that plugin at the moment. And as far as I understand, the plugin does not use the XJC tool of the JDK, is that right?  It's also not an option to use the ogc-schemas project artifacts because we want full control of the generation process and the WFS classes are just a side product of some classes we generate for custom schemas.

Comment: Please understand me correctly, I don't want to push my things, but I would like to know what holds you back so that I could improve.

Comment: 1. (On `maven-jaxb2-plugin`.) Why exactly is `maven-jaxb2-plugin` not an option? It uses JAXB RI XJC, *the same* XJC which is bundel with JDK but *not* the classes from JDK. Using XJC classes from JDK would actually be a bad idea as this would make builds JDK-dependent. You could see changes even between updates in the same minor version (1.7.0_*V1* vs 1.7.0_*V2*). But it is the very same XJC. Why is it a problem for you?

Comment: 2. (On `ogc-schemas`.) This is a valid reason. A small hint: consider using [episodic compilation](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki/Using-Episodes). You can *still* use the `ogc-schemas` artifacts when compiling your custom schemas (WFS/GML profiles, I guess). But even if not, I hope you'll find the binding files helpful. Would you mind contacting me (valikov-at-gmx.net)? I think your case (compiling own schemas with OGC schemas) is a use case the project should support so I'd like to write a guide on that. But would be good to learn, what you're doing.

Comment: maven-jaxb2-plugin is not an option (at the moment) because of some company internal policy I don't have influence on... However, I also ran XJC directly from the command line using the XJC args from the maven log. It works perfectly on linux but not on windows using the same JDK (1.6.0_20).

Comment: I understand your position (but not the internal policy). `maven-jaxb2-plugin` actually does a few workarounds around known XJC bugs. So, sorry, your policymaker seems to put you in a stalemate situation. Of course the solution is possible but it basically mean reinventing the wheel already implemented in the `maven-jaxb2-plugin`. I'm sorry.